# in bash script: how to use printf to print a unique string containing some \n \t

Tags: string, bash, printf

I want to print `$Usage` using `printf` into a bash script.

```
Usage="Usage: \n \   
\tjkl [-lbmcdxh] [-f filename]\n \  
\t\t[-h] \tThis usage text.\n \  
\t\t[-f filename] \t cat the specified file. \n \  
\t\t[-l] \tGo to application log directory with ls. \n \  
\t\t[-b] \tGo to application bin directory. \n \  
\t\t[-c] \tGo to application config directory.\n \  
\t\t[-m] \tGo to application log directory and more log file.\n \  
\t\t[-d] \tTurn on debug information.\n \  
\t\t[-x] \tTurn off debug information.\n"
```

How can I print it using `printf`?

I was thinking about using this:

```
printf "%s\n" $Usage
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: for me `printf $Usage` works, or you can use `echo -e $Usage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point here is the lack of double quotes. Once you add them, you are done! This is because the quotes enable the expansion.

```
$ printf "$Usage"
Usage: 
 \   
    jkl [-lbmcdxh] [-f filename]
 \  
        [-h]    This usage text.
 \  
        [-f filename]    cat the specified file. 
 \  
        [-l]    Go to application log directory with ls. 
 \  
        [-b]    Go to application bin directory. 
 \  
        [-c]    Go to application config directory.
 \  
        [-m]    Go to application log directory and more log file.
 \  
        [-d]    Turn on debug information.
 \  
        [-x]    Turn off debug information.
```

`echo` together with `-e` enables interpretation of backslash escapes, so this would also work:

```
echo -e "$Usage"
```

See the difference of quoting or not quoting in a simpler case:

```
$ printf "hello \nman\n"
hello 
man
$
$ printf hello \nman\n
hello$
```

Finally, you may want to have a good read to: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/40596).

Comment: Nice to read that! Note I ended up writing a broader version of Dodon's answer, since his was lacking detail and insight.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
printf "$Usage"
```

or

```
printf "%b" "$Usage"
```

From man 1 printf:

```
 %b     ARGUMENT as a string with `\' escapes interpreted, except that octal escapes are of the form \0 or \0NNN
```

If using `%b` don't forget to add double quotes around the argument

Comment: the output is not neat: it shows `Gotoapplicationlogdirectorywithls.` instead of `Go to application log directory with ls.`. At least to me.

Comment: That was because I forgot to add the quotes around $Usage, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Ok then, `printf "$Usage"` suffices. Since you saw the issue being the double quotes, I suggest you to add it into your answer, because it's the issue here.